# Web app log is not effected when starting Tomcat 7 by Bootstrap

Tags: tomcat, logging, bootstrapping

**Background:**

I have created a bat file on windows, in which a java class will be started. The bat file looks like: `java system.configure.Strap "%ROOT_DIR%" "start"`

The class `system.configure.Strap` first makes some check, then starts Tomcat server by using the Bootstrap class in startup.jar provided by Tomcat. We already have one web app called Manager in Tomcat.

**Problem:**

After executing the bat file, there is a screen in which you can see the startup process of the Tomcat. The log information is only logged on the screen, not into the log file anymore.

1. When using startup.bat provided by Tomcat, the log of the app will be not only logged on the screen,but logged to the file `manager\WEB-INF\log\manager.log`，just as the log4j.xml in app manager has defined.
2. When using the bat file I created,there is just nothing in file `manager\WEB-INF\log\manager.log`

In both cases, Tomcat will startup with no mistakes. Tomcat version is 7.0.42. I have no idea why this problem exists, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just put log4j.jar to the classpath of the java `system.configure.Strap`.

I guess when `system.configure.Strap` starts Tomcat using Bootstrap provided by Tomcat need `commons-logging.jar`, when Bootstrap deploys the web app manager, it needs `log4j.jar`.